# autohotkey: bind <Enter> to <Control> while retaining certain behaviors

Tags: autohotkey

Is there a way to bind the `<ENTER>` key to `<CONTROL>` key, while retaining certain behavior of `<ENTER>` key?

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

- Pressing `<ENTER>` and "a" results in `<CONTROL>` + "a"
- Pressing `<ENTER>` and "1" results in `<CONTROL>` + "1"
- Pressing `<ENTER>` alone results in `<ENTER>`
- Pressing `<ENTER>` and `<ALT>` results in `<ENTER>` + `<ALT>`

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too tough, I've not had time to test it but at least it's a starting point.

```
!enter:: send {alt down} {enter} {alt up}
enter down::
  settimer, timer, on
  hotkey, enter down, off
  return
enter up::
  settimer, timer, off
  send, {ctrl up}
  if a_timesincelasthotkey >= 750
    send, {enter}
  return
timer:
  settimer, timer, off
  send {ctrl down}
  while getkeystate( "enter", "p" )
    sleep, 1
  send, {ctrl up}
  return
```

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know about `settimer`, will look into that. In the meantime, I've written a Python script to "brute force" the behavior by creating multiple hotkeys: https://github.com/YongJieYongJie/autohotkey-script-generator/blob/master/ahk-script-gen.py